# Error: unresolvable extensions in compiling protobuf js

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, protobufjs

My `protobufjs` version is `7.1.2` and my `protobufjs-cli` is in version `1.0.2`. When I wanna compile my proto files I got this error:

```
Error: unresolvable extensions: 'extend google.protobuf.FileOptions' in .grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_openapiv2.options, 'extend google.protobuf.MethodOptions' in .grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_openapiv2.options, 'extend google.protobuf.MessageOptions' in .grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_openapiv2.options, 'extend google.protobuf.ServiceOptions' in .grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_openapiv2.options, 'extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions' in .grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_openapiv2.options, 'extend google.protobuf.MessageOptions' in .validate, 'extend google.protobuf.OneofOptions' in .validate, 'extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions' in .validate, 'extend google.protobuf.MethodOptions' in .google.api
```

What is the problem?